# Iterate over two dataframes' columns and str.encode in utf8

Tags: python, pandas, loops, unicode, encode

I'm currently running on Python 2.7 and have two dataframes x and y. I would like to use some sort of list comprehension to iterate over both columns and use str.encode('UTF8) on each column to get rid of unicode.

This works perfectly fine and is easily readable but wanted to try to use something faster and more efficient.

```
for col in y:
  if y[col].dtype=='O':
    y[col] = y[col].str.encode("utf-8")

for col in x:
  if x[col].dtype=='O':
    x[col] = x[col].str.encode("utf-8")
```

Other methods I have tried:

```
1.)[y[col].str.encode("utf-8") for col in y if y[col].dtype=='O' ]

2.)y.columns= [( y[col].str.encode("utf-8") if y[col].dtype=='O' else y[col]) for col in y ]

3.)y.apply(lambda x : (y[col].str.encode("utf-8") for col in y if y[col].dtype=='O'))
```

I am getting valueerrors and length mismatch errors for 2.) and 3.)

Comment: always show full `Traceback` in question.

Comment: write list comprehension as normal `for` loop so maybe error will show which part of code makes problem, and you may add `print()` in normal `for` loop to see values in variables. You could also use `len()` to if there is `length mismatch errors`

Comment: I don't understand two things: (1) why do you assing result to `y.columns` instead of `y[col]` ? (2) `apply()` gives you `x` but you don't convert it - in place of single value `x` you try to put `y[col]` or rather generator `(...)`.

Comment: in `apply()` you use `(y[col] ... )` and this code creates generator.

Comment: y.apply(lambda y : (y.str.encode("utf-8") for col in y if y.dtype=='O')) does this seem reasonable?

Comment: `apply()` gives you value from single cell, not full column - see code in @coldspeed answer - `u.apply(lambda x: x.str.encode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `select_dtypes` to get object columns, then call `apply` over each column to encode it:

```
u = df.select_dtypes(include=[object])
df[u.columns] = u.apply(lambda x: x.str.encode('utf-8'))
```

---

Write a small function to do this and call it for each dataframe.

```
def encode_df(df):
    u = df.select_dtypes(include=[object])
    df[u.columns] = u.apply(lambda x: x.str.encode('utf-8'))
    return df

x, y = encode_df(x), encode_df(y)
```

Comment: even after applying both of those methods I still see this for all columns

Index([u'Name', u'Type'], dtype='object')

Comment: @TH14 You have not shown your data, so there is nothing further I can do to help you. I suggest opening a new question and explaining why the current answer does not work.

Comment: what exactly are the implications of the unicode "u" in column names?

Comment: @TH14 It's a python2 thing where strings could either be `str` or `unicode`. Now-a-days, strings only have a single type: `str`.

Comment: oh okay got it, thank you for your help! I'm not used to dealing with unicode issues since I've only ever worked with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[11,12,13,14]})

def f(x):
    return x**2

pd.DataFrame([[f(i) for i in tuple(v)] for k,v in df.iterrows()], columns=df.columns)
```

```
Out[54]: 
    a    b
0   1  121
1   4  144
2   9  169
3  16  196
```

Comment: [Don't use `iterrows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4909087). You can directly iterate over `df.values` or `zip` just the two columns you need together.